# dplyr to store mutliple variables from a vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I am performing eigen decomposition on a a posterior distribution of 4x4 variance-covariance matrices. To do this I use the `eigen` function in a dplyr/tidyverse pipeline:

```
set.seed(1)
# Variance and covariances of 4 variables
A1  <- rnorm(1000,10,1)
A2  <- rnorm(1000,10,1)
A3  <- rnorm(1000,10,1)
A4  <- rnorm(1000,10,1)
C12 <- rnorm(1000,0,1)
C13 <- rnorm(1000,0,1)
C14 <- rnorm(1000,0,1)
C23 <- rnorm(1000,0,1)
C24 <- rnorm(1000,0,1)
C34 <- rnorm(1000,0,1)

# Create posterior tibble
w1_post <- as_tibble(cbind(A1, C12, C13, C14, A2, C23, C24, A3, C34, A4))

# Get 1st-4th eigenvalues of each variance-covariance matrix
w1_post %>%
  rowwise %>%
    mutate(
      eig1 = 
        eigen(matrix(c(A1, C12, C13, C14, C12, A2, C23, C24, C13, C23,
          A3, C34, C14, C24, C34, A4), nrow = 4))[[1]][1],
      eig2 = 
        eigen(matrix(c(A1, C12, C13, C14, C12, A2, C23, C24, C13, C23,
          A3, C34, C14, C24, C34, A4), nrow = 4))[[1]][2],
      eig3 = 
        eigen(matrix(c(A1, C12, C13, C14, C12, A2, C23, C24, C13, C23,
          A3, C34, C14, C24, C34, A4), nrow = 4))[[1]][3],
      eig4 = 
        eigen(matrix(c(A1, C12, C13, C14, C12, A2, C23, C24, C13, C23,
          A3, C34, C14, C24, C34, A4), nrow = 4))[[1]][4]) %>%
  select(starts_with('eig')) -> eig_post
```

Producing

```
> eig_post
Source: local data frame [1,000 x 4]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 1,000 x 4
    eig1  eig2  eig3  eig4
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  12.3 11.0  10.4   6.67
 2  12.8 10.1   9.19  7.61
 3  13.5 12.2   8.20  7.34
 4  12.7 12.2   8.91  7.68
 5  12.9  9.70  9.41  6.74
 6  12.2 10.6   8.62  7.70
 7  13.1 12.5   9.21  8.34
 8  12.9  9.76  7.87  6.96
 9  12.8 11.6   8.21  6.46
10  12.5 11.6   9.85  8.13
# ... with 990 more rows
```

As you can see, this is performing the eigen decomposition four times per row - that's 4x more than is really necessary and slowing down my script! **Can I get a dplyr/tidyverse pipe to mutate multiple variables at once, spreading the vector produced by `eigen(*matrix*)[[1]][1:4]` across the four variables?** So I need to get what the above code produces, but only doing one eigen decomposition per row. I thought something like this would work but no luck:

```
w1_post %>%
  rowwise %>%
    mutate(c(eig1, eig2, eig3, eig4) = 
      eigen(matrix(c(A1, C12, C13, C14, C12, A2, C23, C24, C13, C23,
        A3, C34, C14, C24, C34, A4), nrow = 4))[[1]][1:4]) %>%
  select(starts_with('eig')) -> eig_post
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid calculating the eigen decomposition 4 times by storing the calculation first as a list-column, and then just extracting the values in a subsequent step. If you want to keep it in your pipeline, you can do it like this:

```
eig_post <- w1_post %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(
    pre_eig = list(eigen(matrix(c(A1, C12, C13, C14, C12, A2, C23, C24, C13, C23,
                     A3, C34, C14, C24, C34, A4), nrow = 4)))
  ) %>%
  mutate( 
    eig1 = pre_eig[[1]][1], 
    eig2 = pre_eig[[1]][2], 
    eig3 = pre_eig[[1]][3], 
    eig4 = pre_eig[[1]][4]) %>%
  select(starts_with("eig"))
```

Comment: thanks - works like a charm; as a side note I changed it to perform the mutates all in the same mutate: `mutate(pre_eig = list(eigen(matrix(c(A1, C12, C13, C14, C12, A2, C23, C24, C13, C23,
                     A3, C34, C14, C24, C34, A4), nrow = 4))), eig1 = pre_eig[[1]][1], eig2 = pre_eig[[1]][2], eig3 = pre_eig[[1]][3], eig4 = pre_eig[[1]][4])`

Comment: that's of course also possible, but for sake of clarity I split it up in the answer. A quick microbenchmark test showed btw that this approach is at least 3x faster than your original approach

Comment: a follow up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52833634/automated-rowwise-matrix-extraction-in-dplyr

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that makes use of `purrr::map` family of functions:

```
eig_post <- w1_post %>%

    ## Collapse columns into a vector
    transmute( x = pmap( list(A1, C12, C13, C14, C12, A2, C23, C24, C13, C23,
                              A3, C34, C14, C24, C34, A4), c ) ) %>%

    ## Compose the 4x4 matrices from each vector
    mutate( mtx = map( x, matrix, nrow=4 ) ) %>%

    ## Perform a single decomposition and retrieve all 4 eigenvalues
    mutate( eig = map( mtx, ~eigen(.x)$values ) ) %>%

    ## Annotate the vector of eigenvalues with the desired names
    mutate( eig = map( eig, set_names, str_c("eig", 1:4) ) ) %>%

    ## Reshape the data frame by effectively unnesting the vector
    with( invoke( bind_rows, eig ) )
```

Comment: this appears to be slightly faster than my method still (around 25 % faster)